# SQL - Get Minutes between 2 datetime but only for Workdays

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a requirement to get the number of minutes between 2 date times.  The problem is that I need only to count the minutes during the week.  My weekend hours do not count.  Additional we define the weekend as starting from 5pm on Friday and ending on 8am Monday.  I believe I have created a function that will calculate time during the week but it does not account for the time between Friday 17:00-23:59 and Monday 00:00-7:59.  This calculation could span across multiple weeks so it needs to filter out this time each week.

Some examples of expected results are:

- 09/09/15 09:15 - 09/10/15 18:30 = 1995 Minutes
- 09/09/15 09:15 - 09/11/15 18:30 = 3345 Minutes (counter only goes to 5pm on Friday)
- 09/09/15 09:15 - 09/12/15 18:30 = 3345 Minutes
- 09/09/15 09:15 - 09/13/15 18:30 = 3345 Minutes
- 09/09/15 09:15 - 09/14/15 18:30 = 3975 Minutes (and counter starts back at 8pm Monday)
- 09/11/15 18:30 - 09/12/15 18:30 = 0 Minutes (because the counter started after 5pm on Friday and did not go until Monday at 8am.
- 09/12/15 18:30 - 09/14/15 18:30 = 630 Minutes

Here is the function so far:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'WorkDaysMinutes', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkDaysMinutes]
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WorkDaysMinutes] (@StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME = NULL) RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Swap DATETIME
    DECLARE @Weekend_Start_Time NVARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @Weekend_End_Time NVARCHAR(5)

    SET @Weekend_Start_Time = '17:00'
    SET @Weekend_End_Time = '08:00'

    IF @StartDate IS NULL
        RETURN NULL

    IF @EndDate IS NULL
        SELECT @EndDate = @StartDate

    IF @StartDate > @EndDate
        SELECT @Swap      = @EndDate,
               @EndDate   = @StartDate,
               @StartDate = @Swap

    RETURN (
        SELECT
    --Start with total number of minutes including weekends
        DATEDIFF(MI,@StartDate, @EndDate)
    --Subtact 2880 minutes for each full weekend
        -(DATEDIFF(wk, DATEADD(dd,-1,@StartDate), DATEADD(dd,-1,@EndDate)) * 2880)
    --If StartDate is a Weekend, Subtract time untill monday
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN DATEDIFF(MI,@StartDate,DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,-1,@StartDate))) ELSE 0 END)
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Saturday' THEN DATEDIFF(MI,@StartDate,DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,-1,@StartDate))) + 1440 ELSE 0 END)
    --If EndDate is a Weekend, Subtract time since friday
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN DATEDIFF(mi,CONVERT(varchar(10),@EndDate,112),@EndDate) ELSE 0 END)
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Sunday' THEN DATEDIFF(mi,CONVERT(varchar(10),@EndDate,112),@EndDate) + 1440 ELSE 0 END)
    --Subtract all holidays
        -((SELECT Count(*) 
           FROM SY_Holiday H
           WHERE H.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
            AND DATEPART(DW,H.Date) NOT IN (6,7)) * 1440)
        )
    END  
GO
```

EDIT: We also need to account for holidays as well.  These holidays are stored in a table SY_Holiday.  If the holiday falls on a Sat or Sun then it is irrelevant and should not be deducted but if it falls on Tuesday thur Thursday then we would deduct 1440 for each day.  If the holiday falls on a Friday then we will need to deduct the time from Thurday at 5pm until Friday at 5pm.  The same applies for Monday.  This should just mean deducting a flat 1440 should be fine.

Comment: What about national holidays, and other non-working days?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, I forgot to mention that, this is what we have the holidays table for. This will track those days and it should be deducted from the total.  I have edited the original post to highlight the holidays.

Comment: Rather than just implementing a *holiday* table, why not introduce a *calendar* table? With one row for every day, 20 years worth of rows is only ~7000 rows. You can add useful columns such as start times and end times for work for every day and then this query is reduced to just finding rows from this table which overlap the given dates and summing the working minutes for each day found.

Comment: Ok, ill bite.... .how would we do the comparison?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
DECLARE @Swap DATETIME2
DECLARE @Weekend_Start_Time time = '17:00'
DECLARE @Weekend_End_Time time = '08:00'

IF @StartDate > @EndDate
    Select  @Swap = @EndDate, @EndDate = @StartDate, @StartDate = @Swap

    Set @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART(MINUTE, @Weekend_End_Time), DATEADD(HOUR, -DATEPART(HOUR, @Weekend_End_Time), @StartDate)))
    Set @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART(MINUTE, @Weekend_End_Time), DATEADD(HOUR, -DATEPART(HOUR, @Weekend_End_Time), @EndDate)))
    Set @Weekend_Start_Time = DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEPART(MINUTE, @Weekend_End_Time), DATEADD(HOUR, -DATEPART(HOUR, @Weekend_End_Time), @Weekend_Start_Time))

SELECT
    --Start with total number of minutes including weekends
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@StartDate, @EndDate)
    --Subtact 2880 minutes for each full weekend
    - (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 3780)
    --If StartDate is a Weekend, Subtract time untill monday
    - Coalesce(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
        DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, @Weekend_Start_Time) - DATEPART(HOUR, @StartDate),
            DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(MINUTE, @Weekend_Start_Time) - DATEPART(MINUTE, @StartDate),
                DATEADD(d, -Case DATEPART(dw, @StartDate) When 5 then Case When cast(@StartDate as time) > @Weekend_Start_Time then 0 end
                    When 6 then 1 When 7 then 2 End, @StartDate)
                )
            )
        , @StartDate), 0)
    --If EndDate is a Weekend, Subtract time since friday
    - Coalesce(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
        DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, @Weekend_Start_Time) - DATEPART(HOUR, @EndDate),
            DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(MINUTE, @Weekend_Start_Time) - DATEPART(MINUTE, @EndDate),
                DATEADD(d, -Case DATEPART(dw, @EndDate) When 5 then Case When cast(@EndDate as time) > @Weekend_Start_Time then 0 end
                    When 6 then 1 When 7 then 2 End, @EndDate)
                )
            )
        , @EndDate), 0)
```

Note that I change 2880 to 3780. This is the number of minutes from Friday 17:00 to Monday 8:00

Comment: thanks for the help, This works good if the start and end dates are outside the weekend window.  However the calculation goes negative if we start inside a window.

Comment: For example '09/11/15 18:30' to '09/12/15 18:30' should return 0 days but I got -90.

Comment: A extra condition must be added for case 6 for start date and case=2 for start date. I will update my answer later tonight.

Comment: Thanks Julien, also note the requirement for holidays,  I have updated the original code to show the holiday logic.  Is this compatible with your math?

Comment: Holliday table can be added. It should not be an issue. I just remove it because it was easier to test it here.

Comment: Also note that starting in the weekend for example '09/12/15 18:30' to '09/14/15 18:30' bypasses the full weekend logic and results in 2610 minutes instead of the correct 630 minutes.

Comment: It now works with all your date and more. You can add holidays by yourself.

Comment: Line 10 is a syntax error. Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Line 10 was duplicated on itself. I remove it. Make sure parenthesis are ok. I can't test it right now.

Comment: Start '09/11/15 18:30', and End '09/12/15 18:30' goes negative -180.  Another example is Start '2015-01-04 20:51' and End '2015-01-05 15:55' = -5747?